# How can i run a ruby on rails project on apache server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I have project, personal blog with ruby on rails 3.
I use linux.
I want to run this project on apache server, not in webbrick.

How can i do this?

It will be very helpful if someone can answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can take a look at *Passenger**:

http://www.modrails.com/

This is a module for Apache that works like mod_php. It's very easy to setup and you can also use the **Ruby Enterprise Edition** to use "33% less memory on average":

http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/

Comment: I need the process to run it.Not only the link.From that link, i can't understand what to do.Probably i have done, apt-get install apt-get install libapache2-mod-passenger , now what to do ?

Comment: you should follow the instruction on modrails site. you can take a look here: http://www.modrails.com/install.html After executing the command `passenger-install-apache2-module` you get info on how to add a new site as a virtual host on apache.